# Using math mode in a label

Tags: cross-referencing, amsthm

How can one use something like `$\mathbb{R}^k$` in a label? I.e. 
`\label{three equivalent properties of $\mathbb{R}^k$}`.

Currently when I try this I get an error.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, parskip}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

The letter $\mathbb{R}$ prints fine on its own. \\

\begin{thm}
And this theorem causes no issues.
\end{thm}
But putting math in the label is an issue:

\begin{thm}
\label{Putting an $\mathbb{R}$ here is an issue.}
This one can't be printed.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The error message:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'm pretty sure the answer is that you can't but I don't understand why you'd want to.

Comment: Makes it easier to do the labels if I can reference the LaTeX rather than a description I make up, which is likely to be longer (i.e. `$\mathbb{R}^k$` vs. `the set of k-tuples of real numbers`).

Comment: I think you have to be more imaginative ;). `bbR-k`? I use acronyms although they are a little hard to track but only really if I don't work on something for a while. While working on it, they are fresher in my mind.

Comment: I think it would suffice if we can change the active-ness of `_` and `^` under a `\label`, but I'm not sure that's possible with how TeX scans its tokens.  (I'm really not well versed in the topic, though.)

Comment: My opinion is that this is *more* difficult to manage than a simple label like `\label{equiv-properties-R}`

Comment: `\label` is intended to be used (similar to a `id="..."` anchor in HTML) as a short internal identifier for cross referencing, it is not intended to include markup (or even multiple words, although space might work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label is just an identifier for cross references. While it's not strictly required to be a string of characters, it's better to: the argument to `\label` is subject to “full expansion” and commands such as `\mathbb` don't survive it. Commands in the argument to `\label` are commonly used internally, for example when labels are autogenerated from macros for special purposes.

Spaces are allowed, but in my opinion it's better not using them.

You *could* define `\funnylabel` and `\funnyref` macros

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, parskip}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\funnylabel}[1]{%
  \label{\protect\detokenize{\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\funnyref}[1]{%
  \ref{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

The letter $\mathbb{R}$ prints fine on its own.

\begin{thm}
And this theorem causes no issues.
\end{thm}
But putting math in the label is an issue:

\begin{thm}
\funnylabel{Putting an $\mathbb{R}$ here is an issue.}
This one can't be printed.
\end{thm}

\funnyref{Putting an $\mathbb{R}$ here is an issue.}

\end{document}
```

but I strongly discourage you doing so. Besides, I firmly believe that

```
\label{equiv-properties-Rk}
```

is much better than

```
\funnylabel{three equivalent properties of $\mathbb{R}^k$}
```

because it's easier to type and to memorize.

Comment: I'm curious: what is the motivation for expanding the argument of `\label` in the design of LaTeX?

Comment: @JPi `\write` operations do full expansion.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Sorry for having been late.

Comment: @egreg Don't be silly. You're not anyone's personal researcher here. :P